# re.sub tries to escape repl string?

Tags: python, regex

So this doesn't work with python's regex:

```
>>> re.sub('oof', 'bar\\', 'foooof')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 270, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 257, in _compile_repl
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

I thought my eyes were deceiving me, so I did this:

```
>>> re.sub('oof', "bar\x5c", 'foooof')
```

Got the same thing. I've searched and have confirmed people have this problem. So what's the problem with treating repl as just an ordinary string? Are there additional formatting options that can be in placed in repl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the replacement string is processed for escape characters. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash
>   escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single
>   newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth.
>   Unknown escapes such as \j are left alone. Backreferences, such as \6,
>   are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I must have overlooked it. So yes there is additional formatting in repl. Neat.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the string escapes to be processed, you can use a lambda and the string is not processed:

```
>>> re.sub('oof', lambda x: 'bar\\', 'foooof')
'foobar\\'
>>> s=re.sub('oof', lambda x: 'bar\\', 'foooof')
>>> print s
foobar\
```

But it will still be interpreted when printed:

```
>>> re.sub('oof', lambda x: 'bar\r\\', 'foooof')
'foobar\r\\'
>>> print re.sub('oof', lambda x: 'bar\r\\', 'foooof')
\oobar
```

Or, use a raw string:

```
>>> re.sub('oof', r'bar\\', 'foooof')
'foobar\\'
```

Comment: That was in the pydocs too, I gotta read better. I like this option more than escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Use raw strings:

```
re.sub('oof', r'bar\\', 'foooof')
```

without the `r` prefix, you need to have double escaped backslashes:

```
re.sub('oof', 'bar\\\\', 'foooof')
```

Comment: No, I mean why does I need to escape the backslashes of the replacement string? Why is there additional processing for the replacement string is what I'm asking. Shouldn't it replace the matching segments with whatever `repl` is and not ask questions?

Answer (score -1):

Did you expect `foobar\` as the output? If so, `re.sub('oof', r'bar\\', 'foooof')` is what you need; the `r` tells Python to treat what follows as a raw string and thus backslashes are treated as backslashes instead of working as as sign that the following character needs to be treated specially. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)'s a section in the documentation that explains this in more detail.